# Visual studio 2015 community install update 1 Failed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

#### Visual studio 2015 community install update 1 Failed

Windows 10, Visual studio 2015 community, Update 1 (November 30, 2015)

Error message:

> Visual Studio Professional 2015 is currently installed on this
>   machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2015 and retry.

[image]

Comment: I'm having similar issues

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the same issue then installing update1 to the visual studio 2015 community.

[install error, link to the image and text:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YhSi0.png)

> Visual Studio Professional 2015 is currently installed on this
>   machine. Please uninstall Visual Studio Professional 2015 and retry.

In past i installed plugin *Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects* that didn't work with VS 2015 community and work with VS 2015 profession.

This recipe was:

1) Launch RegEdit

2) if win32:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"
    if win64:
    Select key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0"

3) In that key/subkey, you must create two new subkeys:
    "professional"
    "vscore"

4) In each of the subkeys you have just created create a REGSZ value (=string) with the name "Install" and value "1" (yes: "1" is a string!)

---

**To solve the problem in VS 2015 community you had to rename or delete a folder in the registry "professional"**

[Before community folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAFUL.png)

[Before professional folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hJYD.png)

[vscore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n46lP.png)

[After professional folder, picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NRNbU.png)

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue. Solution that worked for me, delete the registry key:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\DevDiv\vs\Servicing\14.0

(Machine: Windows 10, 64 bit, Visual Studio 2015 Community)